# React Native CameraRole does not work despite linking

Tags: react-native

I have tried to get the react-native CameraRole module to work, but despite following the tutorial multiple times, the library will not work. I have tried to link with both rnpm and the manual method, both have no effect on the build.

The code I am running is:

```
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native'
CameraRoll.getPhotos()
```

The error I get is:

[image]

I have linked the the module in xcode by adding the RCTCameraRoll.xcodeproj file to Libraries and added the Products/libRTCCameraRoll.a to the main projects Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries

I am out of ideas, as nothing seems to work. Have I missed something?

EDIT:

Fixed typo

Comment: You've got a typo: `CameraRole !== CameraRoll`

Comment: Whoops sorry, the issue is with CameraRoll too. Stating: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RTCCameraRollManager.getPhotos')

Comment: @wazzaday Did you figure out the issue? I'm dealing with the same thing